# Use Method that returns an Int inside a Stream

Tags: methods, java-8, get, java-stream, collectors

I have a simple method :

```
public int getPrice(String bookingName) 
{
 //return the price of a booking
}
```

I also have the class :

```
public class Booking 
{
String name;
...
}
```

I want to group the bookings in a map(key = name of the booking, value = getPrice(bookingName)) so I did :

```
public TreeMap<String, Integer> bookingForName() {
    return  bookings.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getName,Collectors.summingInt(getPrice(Booking::getName))));

}
```

This doesnt' work it says :

Multiple markers at this line:

```
- The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
- The method getPrice(String) in the type Manager is not applicable for the arguments `(Booking::getName)`
```

How can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: `bookings.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getName,TreeMap::new,Collectors.summingInt(b->getPrice(Booking::getName))));`

Comment: @HadiJ not quite. `getPrice` won't accept `Booking::getName`. It expects a String.

Comment: Thanks @Eran, just copied OP post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getPrice()` method takes a `String`, not a functional interface, so you can't call `getPrice(Booking::getName)`, and even if you could, `summingInt` doesn't accept an `int`.

Change:

```
Collectors.summingInt(getPrice(Booking::getName))
```

to:

```
Collectors.summingInt(b -> getPrice(b.getName()))
```

Also note that `Collectors.groupingBy` returns a `Map`, not a `TreeMap`. If you must have a `TreeMap`, you should call a different variant of `groupingBy`.

```
public TreeMap<String, Integer> bookingForName() {
    return bookings.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getName,
                                                  TreeMap::new,
                                                  Collectors.summingInt(b -> getPrice(b.getName()))));

}
```

Comment: There’s one missing `)`. Besides that, `getName()` in key *and* value is redundant. You can use `return bookings.stream().map(Booking::getName) .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getPrice, Integer::sum, TreeMap::new));`

Comment: @Holger thanks. I was sure I counted the parentheses correctly.  I  like your suggested alternative.